# How to check if a directory exists in a Chef recipe NOT_IF?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-solo

In a Chef recipe I've a bash resource that basically download and install a software named Revolution R. I must say that I'm really a noob in Ruby.

This is my resource:

```
bash 'download_revolutionr' do
    code <<-EOH
    mkdir -p /tmp/RRO-#{rro_version}
    wget https://mran.revolutionanalytics.com/install/RRO-#{rro_version}-#{rro_os_platform}-#{rro_os_version}.x86_64.deb -P /tmp/RRO-#{rro_version}
    wget https://mran.revolutionanalytics.com/install/RevoMath-#{rro_version}.tar.gz -P /tmp/RRO-#{rro_version}
    tar -xzf /tmp/RRO-#{rro_version}/RevoMath-#{rro_version}.tar.gz -C /tmp/RRO-#{rro_version}
    EOH
  not_if { ::Dir.exists?("/tmp/RR0-" + rro_version) }
end
```

My idea is to do not download the software if there are already on the disk inside the /tmp/RRO-version directory. So that, I added the not_if condition with the Dir.exists. But the resource is executed anyway (and a new useless copy of the software is downloaded).

Any idea of what's wrong with this?

Comment: Not sure I see it correctly but "RRO" folder name seems to be spelled with a zero at the end as RR0 in the guard statement "::Dir.exists?("/tmp/RR0-" + rro_version)"

Comment: Just use interpolation as in the rest of the code: `::Dir.exists?("/tmp/RR0-#{rro_version}")` in addition to @IsabelHM comment above.

Comment: sorry for the typo. But the error was actually only here, not in the real code. However, I was ablt to find the error: it was a very stupid permission issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest checking out out the [ark cookbook](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/ark) for handling remote archive packages.

```
include_recipe "ark"

ark 'RevoMath' do
  url 'https://mran.revolutionanalytics.com/install/RevoMath-1.0.1.tar.gz'
end
```

Which will install the tar package content into the **/usr/local/RevoMath-1.0.1** directory. These defaults can be overridden.

Comment: tnx! this is definitivaly a more idiomatic solution rather than mine.